# What is the datatype of return in this function?

Tags: swift, realm

I created two realm `Object` classes called : `Master` and `Courses`

```
class Master : Object , Identifiable {
    
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID()
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    var courses = List<Course>()
    
}

class Course : Object , Identifiable {
    
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID()
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    var parentMaster = LinkingObjects(fromType:Master.self , property: "courses")
    
}
```

ViewModel :

```
class AppState : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var allmasters : [Master] = []

}
```

I have a simple function to return courses for each master here :

```
   func input(index: Int) -> List<Course> {
       
        return appState.allmasters[index].courses

    }
```

**My problem is :** what is the `datatype` of `return` for function?? I put `List<Course>` as a return type but the compiler give me this error :

> Generic type 'List' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1,
> but expected 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are importing both `SwiftUI` and `RealmSwift` in the same file, both of which declare a `List` type.

If you want to return a `RealmSwift.List`, you need to declare the return type as such.

```
func input(index: Int) -> RealmSwift.List<Course> {   
    return appState.allmasters[index].courses
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)  ,` RealmSwift.List<Course> ` works edit your answer to accept as a right answer

Comment: Do you know how can I return an empty List<Course>?Is it right RealmSwift.List<Course>()

Comment: @fdvfarzin updated my answer and yes, `RealmSwift.List<Course>()` is the way to create an empty list.